# Geoprocessing Split does not preserve field domains ArcGIS Pro 3.1.3

Tags: arcgis-pro, geoprocessing, splitting

I have a file geodatabase with a single polygon feature class and a field domain defined for an attribute.
I have a shapefile as a blade.
When Splitting is started, the output geodatabase tables do not retain field domains.
How can I store field domains?

[image]

Comment: It might be useful to change the blade source to file geodatabase.

Comment: I just did a test with the blade saved in a geodatabase file, it doesn't work, it doesn't preserve field domains.
Maybe I need to set something up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote to ESRI ITALIA technical support and they claim that field domains are defined at geodatabase levels and not at feature class level, splitting creates new geodatabase files and new feature classes and therefore does not inherit any field domains.

The solution is to create an arcPy script or graphical model and reassign all output geodatabase files the starting field domain.